# quiver vector arrows are not aligned with original gridpoints in pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, direction

I am working on flow velocity plots over dunes, I do this in python with matplotlib using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = [0.0, 0.03, 0.06, 0.09, 0.29, 0.49]
z = [0.0, 0.09, 0.18, 0.27]
V = [-0.4, -0.2, -0.5, -0.6, -0.1, -0.1,
     0.2, 0.1, 0.05, -0.05, 0.2, 0.3,
     0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 
     0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.8,0.9]
V = np.array(V)
V= V.reshape(4,6)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
velocity = ax.pcolormesh(x,z,V, shading='gouraud', cmap='coolwarm', vmin=-0.8, vmax=0.8)
fig.suptitle('streamwise velocity over dunes')
fig.colorbar(velocity, label='m/s')
plt.xlabel('streamwise distance (m)')
plt.ylabel('height (m)')
xfill = [0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.49]
yfill = [0.07, 0.06, 0, 0.07]
plt.fill_between(xfill, yfill,color='white')
plt.plot(xfill, yfill,color='white')
plt.show()
```

That gives me the following output:
[image: pcolormesh plot flow velocities over dune]

Yet, I would like to add vectors to the velocity observations, and I tried with plt.quiver:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = [0.0, 0.03, 0.06, 0.09, 0.29, 0.49]
z = [0.0, 0.09, 0.18, 0.27]
V = [-0.4, -0.2, -0.5, -0.6, -0.1, -0.1,
     0.2, 0.1, 0.05, -0.05, 0.2, 0.3,
     0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 
     0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.8,0.9]
V = np.array(V)
V= V.reshape(4,6)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
velocity = ax.pcolormesh(x,z,V, shading='gouraud', cmap='coolwarm', vmin=-0.8, vmax=0.8)
fig.suptitle('streamwise velocity over dunes')
fig.colorbar(velocity, label='m/s')
plt.xlabel('streamwise distance (m)')
plt.ylabel('height (m)')
xfill = [0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.49]
yfill = [0.07, 0.06, 0, 0.07]
plt.fill_between(xfill, yfill,color='white')
plt.plot(xfill, yfill,color='white')

x, z = np.meshgrid(x, z)
plt.quiver(x,z,V)
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, the velocity arrows do not match the x and z axis anymore, but follow integers:
[image: velocity vectors, not aligned with original coordinates and also tend upwards]

Furthermore, the velocity vectors also tend to point in vertical direction, whereas I only want to have velocity vectors that point in a horizontal direction (either to the right and positive, or to the left and thus negative)

Is there a way to fix these two problems?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) for `quiver`.

You are missing one argument.
Adding a zero as a y-component of the velocity should solve both your problems.

```py
U = np.zeros_like(V)
plt.quiver(x, z, V, U, pivot='mid')

# Update the limits to make all the velocities visible
ax.set_xlim(x.min()-0.05, x.max()+0.05)
ax.set_ylim(z.min()-0.01, z.max()+0.01)
```

Also, note that u normally denotes the speed in x-direction and v the speed in y-direction; maybe consider renaming your variables.

[image: streamwise velocity over dunese - horizontal quiver]